# Cannot mount custom conf file

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm trying to create a Nginx server using Kubernetes and the official docker image. Unfortunately, when I'm trying to mount a custom config file, nothing happen. My container works just fine but with it's default configuration file. Moreover the another mount on /etc (the lets encrypt folder) doesn't work too. Nevertheless the certbot mount works just fine...
(If I check inside the container /etc/nginx/nginx.conf it's not the file I'm trying to mount, and /etc/letsencrypt doesn't exist)
I link my deployment file just below..
If someone has an idea and want to help it would be delightful !

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.19.6
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443 
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          subPath: nginx.conf
          readOnly: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: letsencrypt
          mountPath: /etc/letsencrypt
          readOnly: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: certbot
          mountPath: /var/www/certbot
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-config
          nfs: 
            server: 192.168.2.9
            path: /volume1/nginx/nginx.conf     
        - name: letsencrypt
          nfs: 
            server: 192.168.2.9
            path: /volume1/nginx/letsencrypt
        - name: certbot
          nfs: 
            server: 192.168.2.9
            path: /volume1/nginx/certbot
```

**Edit :**
To solve this problem I had to put all my volume mount inside a single volumeMount section and to remove the reference to file in the volume section, like this :

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: nginx-config
      mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      subPath: nginx.conf
      readOnly: true
    - name: letsencrypt
      mountPath: /etc/letsencrypt
      readOnly: true

    - name: certbot
      mountPath: /var/www/certbot
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-config
      nfs: 
        server: 192.168.2.9
        path: /volume1/nginx/    
    - name: letsencrypt
      nfs: 
        server: 192.168.2.9
        path: /volume1/nginx/letsencrypt
    - name: certbot
      nfs: 
        server: 192.168.2.9
        path: /volume1/nginx/certbot
```

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the formatting, as it's illegible; and you will need to say what **is** happening in order for anyone help you change its current behavior to the desired behavior

Comment: first make sure that in  `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  `nginx.conf` contains your custom config.

Comment: Hello, I don't see the problem with the formatting... ? It looks OK on my computer 
No, Kubernetes doesn't show errors but when I go inside the container to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf its the default configuration...

Comment: @tellierflexus Look at the time of the comment. 
The post has been edited twice before you answered, precisely because it WAS illegible when he said that.
Now it's legible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because you are incorrectly referencing your `Volumes`. There is no need to reference the file name at the `Volumes` mount stage:

```yaml
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-config
          nfs: 
            server: 192.168.2.9
            path: /volume1/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Once I applied your config my pod was in `CreateContainerConfigError` status with
`failed to prepare subPath for volumeMount "nginx-config" of container "nginx"` error.

The correct yaml should in this case look like this:

```yaml
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-config
          nfs: 
            server: 192.168.2.9
            path: /volume1/nginx/
```

I have added a line `#This is my custom config` just to know that my custom file was load and there are the results of that:

```sh
➜ keti nginx-deployment-66c5547c7c-nsfzv  -- cat  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

```json
#This is my custom config

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

.....
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.. but when I describe the deployment I notice that in the pod template, there is only one mount that appears, the certbot one (which is working) but all volumes . I'm running on microk8s and I have not the error CreateContainerConfigError you got (Thanks for taking time helping me !)

Comment: Ok my error was to repeat the volumeMount tag and not to put all my volume inside a single volumeMount, I edit my post, thanks !

Comment: @tellierflexus would you mind [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer if that help you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer as community wiki for better visibility of OP solution which was placed as an edit to question instead of answer.

The solution for the problem was combination of OP solution to putt all the volumes mount inside singe `volumeMount` with my answer to remove the reference to a file in the volume section:

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: nginx-config
      mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      subPath: nginx.conf
      readOnly: true
    - name: letsencrypt
      mountPath: /etc/letsencrypt
      readOnly: true

    - name: certbot
      mountPath: /var/www/certbot
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-config
      nfs: 
        server: 192.168.2.9
        path: /volume1/nginx/    
    - name: letsencrypt
      nfs: 
        server: 192.168.2.9
        path: /volume1/nginx/letsencrypt
    - name: certbot
      nfs: 
        server: 192.168.2.9
        path: /volume1/nginx/certbot
```